# Creating a header bar like Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, copyright, design, trademark

If I created a headerbar like Stack Exchange/ SO's site, would I be infringing on copyright or trademark?

For an example, a dropdown on the left with my own logo, and menu options on the right with a search field.

Comment: Very, very unlikely.

Comment: many sites have that kind of technology, so it will all depend on whether you imitate it or copy it. (and I am not even sure if copying it will result in legal issues, but I wouldn't run the risk)

Comment: As insane as design patents are there's far too much prior art to patent any combination of the above in any sort of general case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use any of our code (HTML, CSS, etc.) or logos and you'll be fine.

[Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)